# Unity: how to change runtime code for different platforms?

Tags: unity, macos, build-process

**In Unity, how can I programmatically control what source code is compiled?**

I have a script with various `BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer` calls, allowing me to build all versions of my game. However, I'm using the AVPro Video asset to play video, and it doesn't support 32bit Mac. As such, I need to fall back other video playing code on 32bit Mac. There's no preprocessor directive to differentiate 32bit OSX (like you can do for other platforms https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html ).

However, since I'm building each version in sequence, it seems like I should be able to set some state so that during compilation, the right code is used. I tried this:

```
VersionHandler.onMac32 = true;
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(levels, path, BuildTarget.StandaloneOSXIntel, BuildOptions.None);
VersionHandler.onMac32 = false;
```

And then checking that static variable in game. However, that static is "never set", presumably because the the state of the variable during compilation doesn't affect the value at runtime. **Is there any other way I can "get at" the compiled code and set a flag for certain builds?**

As a fallback, I can manually swap code in every time I build for OSX 32-bit, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Combining  `#if UNITY_32` and `#if UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX` doesnt work?

Comment: That doesn't work; it doesn't look like UNITY_32 is a real directive. :/ As far as I can tell, there isn't a 32vs64 directive.

Comment: That is rather weird, since the [ticket about adding it](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/additional-define-variables) was closed as "completed" . Maybe they didnt add it after all or maybe the final implementation has define of a bit different name? The comments there also suggest alternative solution.

Comment: Hmm, those comments are quite old and are talking about the future features in Unity 5, so I can only assume it was dropped, because it's not in the list of all the other directives. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution feels a bit hacky, but it works:

```
using System;

public static bool IsMac32() {
    #if (UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX)
    return IntPtr.Size == 4;
    #else
    return false;
    #endif
}
```

Comment: You know...sometimes a hacky solution is the only solution. I certainly wouldn't have thought about *checking the size of a pointer.*